# MonoGame - References to Microsoft.Phone assemblies

Tags: windows-phone-7, .net-assembly, monogame

How to cope with the Microsoft Phone specific assemblies when loading the classes inside a MonoGame For Android project (MonoGame FrameWork)? As e.g:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio;
using Microsoft.Phone.Marketplace;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using System.Device.Location;
```

Answer (score 1):

These will have to #if defed out as they are not currently supported under MonoGame.
Background audio should be supported via the Song and Sound classes though.

I think the MarketPlace namespace is an interesting one, and is one that should not be phone specific, as MacOS also has an App Store.

I hope this helps.